# Learning MVC design pattern, but has trouble understanding how to for example render sidebars with dynamic content

Tags: php, html, model-view-controller

I'm learning to code php with MVC as an design pattern. I do think that I have a pretty good understanding of how and what role controllers, models and views has.

But the main problem I seem to have, is how to actually layout the page. 
A typical page example for me would be.

A router looking something like this:

```
Route::('/blogg/[id]', 'controllers/blogg@read');
```

Later, in the controller it would maybe say something like this:

```
public function read($id) 
{
   $this->model->getPost($id);

   View::renderHtml('header', $data);
   View::render('views/blogg/post', $data);
   View::renderHtml('footer', $data);
}
```

Ok, so far, so good. Everything looks clean and straight forward in my mind. This would for example make a page that looks like example B on the picture. Where the Navbar is inside the "renderHtml('header')" view...

But, if I would for example wanting my page to look like example F. Two sidebars sitting on both sides of the screen. How would I go about doing this?

[image]
Let's play with the idea that the sidebars contains different reusable widgets. Like Twitter Feed, or "top blog posts" or whatever. And that different pages, or even different blog posts would dynamically load different widget or information into the two sidebars.

Is this still the responsibility of this controller? Should I simply do something like this:

```
public function read($id) 
{
   $this->model->getPost($id);

   View::renderHtml('header', $data);
   View::renderPartial('sidebar-left', $data);
   View::render('views/blogg/post', $data);
   View::renderPartial('sidebar-right', $data);
   View::renderHtml('footer', $data);
}
```

I do not like this solution at all. Because all of a sudden, the clean MVC pattern i just learned... Seems to become this big mess again.

So... Who is suppose to render the sidebars for example. Who is suppose to populate the sidebars with content dynamically. Where does all of this fit together!? I mean, I shouldn't recreate the sidebar in every view right? I will have many different pages that use the sidebars for completely different purposes for example.

Just for the record I am using a framework, but not a big one like Laravel or CakePHP... A smaller one. I really like it so I would more like to learn the... MVC way of doing this instead of just being recomended to use Laravel or something. Though, please enlighten me how Laravel or the other large frameworks handle this. I'm sure there is a lot of ways to this problem.

Comment: In most frameworks you would just pass the data down, and then let the main view decide where to render the partials...

Comment: What is a main view? Like one master view / layout that decides weather or not there is a sidebar on this page or not? Like one view containing all possible things like, sidebar-left, sidebar-right, navigation bar, content etc? How would the controller pass down, let's say the sidebar-left to the master view then? And how would it tell it what the sidebar needs to display?

Answer (score 0):

In a proper MVC architecture, any output (including templates) technically belongs in a view. However, we often fudge things a bit, defining themes/layouts in the controller to reduce code duplication in the views.

As a general rule of thumb, reusable content appearing within a page, such as a comment section, would be embedded as a template within the view. However, wrapping content such as navigation or the `<head>` block would be handled in the background by the (abstract) controller.

One way I might do this if I were writing the framework from scratch would be to give the abstract controller class `_beforeRender()` and `_afterRender()` hooks, which you could override within each controller. Any navigation elements such as the left and right sidebars that you want to include on each page within that particular controller could then be defined as templates and explicitly referenced once per controller rather than in every action. For instance:

```
/**
 * Applies header and footer to all views, but can be overridden by controllers
 */
abstract class Controller {
    public function _beforeRender($data) {
        View::renderHtml('header', $data);
    }
    public function _afterRender($data) {
        View::renderHtml('footer', $data);
    }
}

class BlogController extends Controller {
    public function post($id) {
        // View will automatically call _beforeRender and _afterRender
        View::render('views/blog/post', $data);
    }
    public function _beforeRender($data) {
        parent::_beforeRender($data);
        View::renderPartial('sidebar-left', $data);
    }
    public function _afterRender($data) {
        View::renderPartial('sidebar-right', $data);
        parent::_afterRender($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: (In "proper" MVC the views would actually be the active components. It's only PHP webframeworks where views are mostly data pits in an unidirectional C→M→V pipe.)

Comment: Hmm... Interesting way of doing it. But let's say the sidebar-left only get's shown to signed-in people then? And another question... I now render the sidebar-left... How does it know what to show? Let's say both BlogController & UserProfileController has a sidebar. How does this same partial view know what to render inside of itself?

Comment: That's why you would have a different `_beforeRender()` method on each controller, and have them refer to different templates. Otherwise you'd just put the header and sidebar in the same template. Mario is correct, though; this is a common deviation from the pure MVC architecture.